# Definite integral of product of functions

Tags: definite-integrals

I know it's not correct to write:

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$$

This result seems obvious, but I can't think of a way to prove that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x) dx$ can't be expressed as a function of the form :$$F\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx;\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx\right)$$

Is it something simple I'm missing ? How can one prove that a definite integral can't be represented as mentioned before ?

Comment: Do you know integration by parts technique? it deals with something related.

Answer (score 4):

Just find two pairs of functions $f_1, g_1$ and $f_2,g_2$ such that $$\int f_1 = \int f_2, \quad\quad \int g_1 = \int g_2$$ but $$\int f_1 g_1 \neq \int f_2 g_2$$

Probably any two pairs you come up with will work.

Comment: For example, $f_1 = f_2 = g_1$ can be some bump function, and $g_2$ can be a translate of that same bump function so that its support is disjoint from the other guys. Then the first integral is positive but the second integral is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let:
$$
\int_a^x f(t)dt=F(x) \qquad  \int_a^x g(t)dt=G(x) 
$$
From the fundamental  theorem of calculus we have
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx} F(x)=f(x) \qquad \dfrac{d}{dx} G(x)=g(x) 
$$

and, using the product rule for derivative:

$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\int_a^x f(t)dt\int_a^x g(t)dt\right]=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[F(x)G(x)\right]=G(x)f(x)+F(x)g(x) \ne f(x)g(x)
$$

Comment: What the OP is asking is how to prove that $Gf+Fg$ will be generally different from $fg$. Certainly there are some lucky cases where they are equal.